# Sticky element is not working in Flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sticky

I've made a code with flex box and sticky.
I want blue div to be sticky and red div to be long and scrollable
Also, wrapper around red and blue div is centered.

However, blue div moves as I scrolled.

```css
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.left {
    margin: 0;
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
}

.right {
    margin: 0;
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
        Hello<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        World
    </div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/buttercrab/8wvmkt3d)

Comment: remove the overflow:auto

Answer (score -1):

the issue is the wraper div doesn't have `max-height` or `height` that is `less than` the left red div, if you did add a height to the wrapper you will get what you want successfully.

and check this question [my-position-sticky-element-isnt-sticky-when-using-flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446671/my-position-sticky-element-isnt-sticky-when-using-flexbox) which has similar issue(but not an exact duplicate) of your question.