# positioning sticky sidebar right beside a centered div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to customize my blog layout by adding a sticky sidebar. I managed to get position:sticky to work as excepted, but I can't figure out how to position the blocks where I want.

I want the main block to be centered, and the sidebar right beside the main block. here's an example of what I'm aiming for: https://theme-next.js.org/  except I want the main block to be centered.
[this is the layout I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJTqZ.png)

I've tried using margin-left with the sidebar, but it doesn't work well in smaller windows, as the left margin is constant and pushes the real content away in smaller windows.
[this is what happens by using margin-left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cFHt.png)

(I'm not sure why the sticky dosen't work here, but it works fine on my website. All I'm trying to figure out is how to position them where I want.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  position: webkit-stiky;
  position: sticky;
  align-self: flex-start;
  height: 1000px;
}

.main {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  margin: auto;
  height: 1600px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #F3FF00;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p>
    this is centered header
  </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p> sidebar here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <p>
      I want this block to be centered;
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: here is why it dont work...(little spoliler..FLEX) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446671/my-position-sticky-element-isnt-sticky-when-using-flexbox

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you need to do here:

1. Set a `top` property for your `sticky` sidebar, or it won't stick
2. Make your `main` element a `flex` parent since we'll need to offset its child element to make it centered with your header.
3. Create an `inner` element for your `main` element so you can move it to the left 80px to accommodate for the sidebar width.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 80px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  position: sticky;
  /* you need a top position set for sticky */
  top: 0;
}

.main {
  height: 1600px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  /* This needs to be a flex parent */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* This element needs to be 100% MINUS the sidebar width of 80px */
  flex: 1 0 calc(100% - 80px);
}

.main-inner {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  /* Move the inner element 80px to the left */
  margin-left: -80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  background-color: #F3FF00;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p>this is centered header</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>sidebar here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="main-inner">
      <p>I want this block to be centered;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I believe this is what you really want:

1. Make the header a `flex` parent as well.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 80px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  position: sticky;
  /* you need a top position set for sticky */
  top: 0;
}

.main {
  height: 1600px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  /* This needs to be a flex parent */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* This element needs to be 100% MINUS the sidebar width of 80px */
  flex: 1 0 calc(100% - 80px);
}

.main-inner {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  /* Move the inner element 80px to the left */
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header-inner {
  background-color: #F3FF00;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  background-color: #F3FF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-inner">
    <p>this is centered header</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>sidebar here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="main-inner">
      <p>I want this block to be centered;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```