# Sticky element inside flexbox (not in combination with)

Tags: css, flexbox, sticky

Many similar questions have been posted to try and achieve position sticky with an element that has flex rules applied (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446671/my-position-sticky-element-isnt-sticky-when-using-flexbox) post is one of many that I tried the answers from), but my aim is to apply `position:sticky` to a **child of a flex element**.

I have a two-column layout with a menu on the left.  The idea is that when the page is scrolled down, the blue-colored menu stays at the top (although the image above should scroll upwards, leaving just the menu visible in it's place).

However, no matter of which combinations of `align-self` I apply, the menu still disappears vertically upwards with the image.

If its possible to combine flex with sticky, then I'm hoping there's also a solution for the child element.

[Fiddle here using SCSS](https://jsfiddle.net/EvilDr/usbcn60h/16/)

```css
.PageContainer {

  .OuterContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    gap: 1em;
    
    .SideOne {
      background-color:#fee;  
      align-self: flex-start /* Solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446671 */; 
      width: 10em;
      
      .CompanyLogo {
        img {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
      
      .MyStickMenu {
        border:1px solid blue;
        background-color:#eef;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        
      }
    }

    .SideTwo {
      background-color:#ddd;
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-shrink: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="PageContainer">

  <div class="OuterContainer">

    <div class="SideOne">

      <div class="CompanyLogo">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100.png" alt="" />
      </div>

      <div class="MyStickMenu">
        <h2>
          Not-so Sticky Menu
        </h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Away</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="SideTwo">

      <h1>
        Scrollable page
      </h1>

      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not with the sticky property but with the expectations you have of it. A sticky element is only sticky within its parent and so the `Side One`'s height limits how far the menu can go.

You're going to have to put the Menu as a sibling to the "sides".

Alternatively you could divide `Side One` into two separate sides one for the menu and one for the rest, applying the `position: sticky` to the new side as it is the one who is supposed to cover its siblings while scrolling.

Comment: The first paragraph helped me with a workaround.  Thank you.

Comment: Quick fixed version for any future visitors although image is also sticky, but its a much better outcome than what I had - https://jsfiddle.net/EvilDr/usbcn60h/19/

Comment: I'd appreciate an upvote if you find this answer satisfactory.