# Sticky child element in display: flex parent

Tags: html, css, sticky

I want my `.sidebar` flex element to be **sticky when I'm scrolling** but `position: sticky; top: 0;` doesn't work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main div {
  width: 300px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <header></header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <button>Upload image</button>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is related with flex box. Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44446672/2007927

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the default property of `align-items` for flex elements is `normal` (acts like `stretch` in this context) therefore the `.sidebar` element takes all the available height and can't have the "sticky effect".
You can achieve the the sticky efect by changing the `align-items` property on the `.container` element to `flex-start` like this :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start; /* <- ADD THIS */
  gap: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main div {
  width: 300px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <header></header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <button>Upload image</button>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*(Note that I also changed the `top`  property on the `.sidebar` element so it doesn't hide under the header)*