# Can't make "only ONE part" of the Navbar sticky - Tailwind

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I have been dealing with this frustrating issue in Tailwind for the past days and have tried almost anything, still can't fix this. I read this post as well: [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446671/my-position-sticky-element-isnt-sticky-when-using-flexbox) but it did not resolve it. Here is the problem:

In the code snippet below, if I put the `"sticky top-0"` in the `<nav>` element's class, the whole navbar becomes sticky and behaves correctly. However, I only want the `<div>` which contains the `<Button>` components and currently has the sticky class to be sticky! But for some reason, this div does not remain sticky when I scroll. what is the issue? I have also included the parent element that contains the navbar after the code snippet below.

**Navbar element:**

```
<nav className="bg-transparent p-6">
  <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-between gap-6 md:flex-row">
    <div className="z-50 flex items-center space-x-5">
      <img src={profileImage} alt="profile image" className="w-16 rounded-full outline outline-2 outline-offset-2 outline-blue-600 md:w-24" />

      <h1 className="text-xl font-bold">Some Text...</h1>
    </div>

    //*** THE PART THAT SHOULD BE STICKY:***//

    <div className="sticky top-0">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
        <NavButton />
        <NavButton />
        <NavButton />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And here is the parent container that holds the `<Navbar>` component:

```
<div className="container mx-auto">
  <NavBar />
  <div className="grid max-w-6xl grid-cols-1 py-6">
    <AlphabeticBlock>
      <Intro />
      <Projects />
      <Contact />
    </AlphabeticBlock>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the `<div>` not being sticky is due to [`sticky` being defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#valdef-position-sticky) as (emphasis mine)

> Identical to `relative`, except that its offsets are automatically adjusted in reference to the nearest ancestor scroll container’s scrollport […], to try to keep the box in view within its **containing block** as the user scrolls.

The containing block of the sticky `<div>` is the `<nav>`, and since the `<nav>` is by and large the same height as the sticky `<div>`, no meaningful sticky behavior is observed visually. Instead, you would need to consider having the sticky `<div>` outside this `<nav>`, in an element that stretches more of the webpage, such as the root-level `<div>` element:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="container mx-auto md:grid md:grid-cols-[1fr_auto] gap-x-6">
  <nav class="bg-transparent p-6 self-center">
    <div class="">
      <div class="z-50 flex items-center space-x-5">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/96/96" alt="profile image" class="w-16 rounded-full outline outline-2 outline-offset-2 outline-blue-600 md:w-24" />

        <h1 class="text-xl font-bold">Some Text...</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="sticky top-0 self-center">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
      <NavButton>NavButton</NavButton>
      <NavButton>NavButton</NavButton>
      <NavButton>NavButton</NavButton>
    </div>
  </div>
      
  <div class="grid max-w-6xl grid-cols-1 py-6 col-span-2">
    <AlphabeticBlock>
      <Intro>Intro</Intro>
      <Projects>Projects</Projects>
      <Contact>Contact</Contact>
    </AlphabeticBlock>
    <Footer class="h-[200vh]">Footer</Footer>
  </div>
</div>
```