# How to make element sticky

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an element sticky but `overflow-x: hidden !important` on the body is preventing from that. Is there a way to achieve that without removing `position: sticky` and `overflow-x: hidden !important;`?
https://codepen.io/Dragomir-Alexandru/pen/MWZbqRq

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
}

.sticky-element {
    /* Adjust other styles for your sticky element as needed */
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class="sticky-element">this is just a test</div>
   <div class="content">
            this is just a test this is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a test            this is just a test this is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a test            this is just a test this is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a test            this is just a test this is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a test            this is just a test this is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a test            this is just a test this is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a test
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "but `overflow-x: hidden !important` on the body is preventing from that." no it doesn't.

Comment: @MattHamer5 I have tried the same with body like that it works but change that to a div with class or create a new file locally and test it out with body, for me it's not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code,

1. It doesn't have `sticky` position, only `-webkit-sticky`, which is not supported.
2. `.sticky-element` is not aligned. (See [My position: sticky element isn't sticky when using flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446671/my-position-sticky-element-isnt-sticky-when-using-flexbox))

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden !important; /* Not a problem */
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-element {
  /* Adjust other styles for your sticky element as needed */
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky; /* Added */
  top: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  align-self: start; /* Added */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="sticky-element">this is just a test</div>
  <div class="content">
    this is just a test this is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a test this is just a test this is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a test this is just a test this is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a test this is just a test this is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a test this is just a test this is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a test this is just a test this is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis
    is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a testthis is just a test
  </div>
</div>
```