# position sticky is not scrolling full with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, sticky

```css
.header,
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.main {
  flex: 0 0 66.6666%;
  height: 1500px;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
  background: gray;
}

.sidebar__widget {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: yellow;
}

.margins {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">header</header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="main">Main</div>
  
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar__widget">
      <div class="margins">
        text2
      </div>
      <div class="margins">
        text3
      </div>
      <div class="margins">
        text4
      </div>
      <div class="margins">
        text5
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>

<footer class="footer">footer</footer>
```

is not scrolling to div with text5, only if i scrolled all content after.

also i recorded a video for showing a problem:
https://gyazo.com/d5337df7b814c0621ac59c1e85433965

also i tried with display: table, it doesn't work correctly too

Comment: Try adding `min-height:100vh;overflow-y:auto;` to `.sidebar` and check

Comment: "sticky" to top effect is not working, it's just scrolling

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446671/my-position-sticky-element-isnt-sticky-when-using-flexbox?rq=2

Comment: i also tried   align-self: flex-start for sidebar__widget; how is recommend, it doesn't working properly

Comment: I'm not sure to understand correctly.. the`.sidebar__widget` container (yellow) is positioned sticky so it will remain stuck relative to `.container` while scrolling its content until its content finished scrolling. The video you shared shows you having a viewport smaller than the yellow box and of course you won't see the `text5` until it will unlock its position due to the scrolling area on its left ended. Once it happens, since you have a footer, the scroll will continue and the yellow will be involved in the scrolling again. Can you be more clear about the expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using this package https://github.com/codecks-io/react-sticky-box and this style

`display: flex; align-items: flex-start;` for container

Issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

The question might not be perfectly clear, but since you showed a video where you had the `.sidebar__widget` (yellow container) taller than the viewport, I supposed you meant that such element had to be sticky only after the scrolling showed it entirely.

To achieve such behaviour you need to change its `top` css property so that if the viewport is taller, it just remains set as `0`, and otherwise it's set with an offset that will stick it only after it's fully shown while still scrolling part of its parent container that includes also a longest content on its left side.

**EDIT**:
Using css only was a more desirable option, but (so far according to what I can see now) it would require your sidebar to lay on the bottom of its container and it might have questionable results when the viewport is higher than its height. In that case you wouldn't see the yellow box starting from the upper edge of its container but you would see it laying on its bottom. Is that what you asked for?

```js
//sets the .sidebar__widget top css property according to window.innerHeight
function adjustStickySidebar() {
    var sidebarWidget = document.querySelector('.sidebar__widget');
    var sidebarHeight = sidebarWidget.offsetHeight;
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

    if (sidebarHeight < windowHeight) {
        sidebarWidget.style.top = '0px';
    } else {
        sidebarWidget.style.top = `${windowHeight - sidebarHeight}px`;
    }
}

//Adjust the sticky sidebar on window load and resize
window.addEventListener('load', adjustStickySidebar);
window.addEventListener('resize', adjustStickySidebar);
```

```css
.header,
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.main {
  flex: 0 0 66.6666%;
  height: 1500px;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
  background: gray;
}

.sidebar__widget {
  position: sticky;
  /*top decides where the elements sticks relative to the container*/
  /*zero works only if the viewport is taller than element's height*/
  top: 0;
  background: yellow;
}

.margins {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">header</header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="main">Main</div>
  
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar__widget">
      <div class="margins">
        text2
      </div>
      <div class="margins">
        text3
      </div>
      <div class="margins">
        text4
      </div>
      <div class="margins">
        text5
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>

<footer class="footer">footer</footer>
```

Comment: it's almost what i want, but if i add more elements, i can't reach text11 block, i keep scrolling but it has no effect for this block
https://gyazo.com/f7f457753be5ca142de606c45d68f23b

if i scroll to the top everything works i expected

Comment: here is another example how it should works
https://gyazo.com/bcadbb617c58db7cb031b26d94e4383f

Answer (score 0):

You need a bottom sticky not a top one. And before that you have to place the element at the bottom as well

```css
.header,
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.main {
  flex: 0 0 66.6666%;
  height: 1500px;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
  background: gray;
  /* add this to place the element at the bottom */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar__widget {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: auto; /* place at bottom */
  background: yellow;
}

.margins {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">header</header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="main">Main</div>
  
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar__widget">
      <div class="margins">
        text2
      </div>
      <div class="margins">
        text3
      </div>
      <div class="margins">
        text4
      </div>
      <div class="margins">
        text5
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>

<footer class="footer">footer</footer>
```

Comment: did you see the result when the viewport is higher than the sidebar height? did you want it to lay on the bottom of its container? doesn't it change the original layout? I ask because my answer used a js approach and as such it's hard to swallow.. but do you think you can keep it css only and still mantain the original layout? Just looking for a better solution of course

Comment: @DiegoD I don't want anything, I am giving an answer. All those questions need to be asked to the OP, not to me.

Comment: I put to your attention the downfall of this answer in a specific scenario. Your comment didn't address my observations and didn't help decoding the issue further. I see you don't care. Never mind

Comment: @DiegoD You are not the OP and based on your comment on the question, you are not even sure what the OP want so why starting a debate on something you are not sure about. If you want more clarfication, discuss/debate with the OP. If you think my answer is not good, downvote it.

Comment: When downvoting I use to explain why. I felt it was fair to ask if you intended (that's why _did you want.._) to change the layout and if you checked what happened when the viewport is higher. You didn't answer to that. I still think this answer was good if it didn't make that change. And I expected a different reaction by the way. My opinion doesn't count that much but in the end I found the reason to undelete my answer that I thought was wrong.