# Html flex in stack widget

Tags: html, css

I set the widget as sticky with HTML, but it does not work as sticky.
When the scroll goes down, the widget goes down.
The structure I want to create

```
Header
page sticky-page title
page-content/sticky widget
```

I don't want to use fixed in any way.

I wanted to show with pictures exactly what I wanted to do. I appreciate your help

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f39c12;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-element {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.sticky-widget {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main-container">
      <!-- Sticky Element -->
      <div class="sticky-element">page STİCK TİTLE</div>
      <!-- Main Content -->
      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="column">
          <!-- Content on the left side -->
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce auctor augue vel mi congue, vel pharetra arcu bi
        </div>
        <div class="column sticky-widget">
          <!-- Example content -->
          <div>WİDGET</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably answered here: [My position: sticky element isn't sticky when using flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446671/my-position-sticky-element-isnt-sticky-when-using-flexbox)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My position: sticky element isn't sticky when using flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446671/my-position-sticky-element-isnt-sticky-when-using-flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

Solution!
Just give

```css
height: 72vh; /* Adjust the value based on your design */
```

in `.sticky-widget` class.

Here is code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f39c12;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-element {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.sticky-widget {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 72vh;
  /* Adjust the value based on your design */
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main-container">
      <!-- Sticky Element -->
      <div class="sticky-element">page STİCK TİTLE</div>
      <!-- Main Content -->
      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="column">
          <!-- Content on the left side -->
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce auctor augue vel mi congue, vel pharetra arcu bi Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem saepe distinctio aperiam illo aliquam enim laboriosam natus hic, blanditiis
          dicta tempore neque fuga eaque quibusdam iusto molestias inventore voluptatibus consequatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum inventore aspernatur tempora rem, placeat deserunt pariatur odit quaerat in fugiat perspiciatis
          nihil nisi libero laboriosam quod ad itaque nam dicta? Ipsam nulla asperiores temporibus corrupti perspiciatis autem maiores minima voluptatum sed corporis eius, expedita assumenda consequatur adipisci iste? Soluta dolorem maxime sed repellat
          corrupti rerum ipsam harum quibusdam deleniti suscipit. Labore soluta dolorum itaque quibusdam sint mollitia dicta, enim, porro, explicabo fuga adipisci voluptates? Accusantium doloribus, neque, sequi quisquam debitis obcaecati ipsa enim hic
          totam cumque perspiciatis ad deserunt vel! Eum cupiditate possimus odit nesciunt doloribus odio ex sed at, aliquid nihil quod voluptas, eaque illum, sequi suscipit ad pariatur fuga libero amet. Placeat ipsum distinctio voluptates, facere corporis
          numquam? Soluta minus culpa minima perspiciatis perferendis magni non, repellendus id pariatur quasi laborum voluptatum? Odit magnam, a fugiat beatae tenetur quisquam eaque animi possimus, quae sunt explicabo quaerat corporis blanditiis! Reiciendis
          praesentium vitae cupiditate cumque quo doloremque eum. Ullam maxime doloribus sapiente inventore perspiciatis. Ratione numquam odit commodi nostrum quam. Voluptates natus repellendus velit reprehenderit sapiente tempora sunt, ea neque! Adipisci
          optio magni sint veniam nihil natus! Consequuntur aspernatur ullam placeat. Inventore omnis eos ipsam, esse optio praesentium obcaecati, voluptas dignissimos possimus repellat nostrum culpa vitae neque cupiditate adipisci. Vel! Minima illo facere
          rem quibusdam minus quisquam, neque ipsa pariatur! Laboriosam repellendus provident dolores eius alias odio magni deserunt. Exercitationem consequatur nihil iusto! Eos iusto minima soluta nostrum fugit magni? Quisquam, maxime, molestias eum
          modi non laborum illum quis veritatis quo similique saepe sunt, numquam suscipit et. A modi fugiat maxime quod eius consectetur odit corporis? Debitis sint voluptatibus cupiditate! Quo dolore ducimus molestias error et nam fugit rerum impedit
          similique qui porro suscipit, quas sed aliquid deleniti maxime expedita nesciunt at beatae dicta sint rem ratione odit natus. Vitae. Dicta reprehenderit praesentium eum id, distinctio ipsam incidunt minus alias eos porro, rerum neque quam voluptas
          iusto magnam nostrum iste quod consequatur modi accusamus beatae ratione esse, autem sed? Eaque? Soluta nostrum magnam voluptate sed minima o ipsum natus laudantium. Voluptates temporibus non amet similique dicta. Suscipit, iure! Nemo accusamus
          alias reiciendis omnis repellendus a illo autem rerum voluptate dolor temporibus est, tempora explicabo consequuntur id!
        </div>
        <div class="column sticky-widget">
          <!-- Example content -->
          <div>WİDGET</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**FEEL FREE TO ASK ANY DOUBTS!**

Comment: Thank you for your answer but "<!-- Content on the left side -->"
it will be "overflow-y" below the paragraph and in that div as well
in one
I want div